# R convert 1 column into several columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

Currently stuck on a data wrangling question in R. So far I've tried variations of this code using tidyverse package, columns 5 and 6 here were the rating and the user:

```
df[,5:6] %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = question, 
              values_from = rating,
              names_sep = ".") %>% 
  unnest(cols = everything())-> df_reformat
```

Each column will be the question ID and the rows are the scores for each user, ideally clustered by group.

Data structure needed:

| repID | user | CSX001 (Customer question 1) | X400m1 (Customer question 2) | .... | Customer question N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| de812 | 717201 | 5 | 4 | ------------------- | 5 |
| de812 | 82200 | 5 | 4 | ------------------- | 3 |

Current data structure (a total of 20,000 rows with differing dimensions based on user size and number of questions given):

| zone | repID | GroupID | Customer question | Rating | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | de812 | levelw001 | CSX001 | 4 | 717201 |
| A001 | de812 | levelw001 | X400m1 | 4 | 82200 |
| A001 | de812 | leveln0075 | bf001s | 5 | 201135 |
| A001 | de812 | levelw001 | X400m1 | 5 | 717201 |
| A001 | de812 | leveln0075 | bf001s | 5 | 82200 |

With the rows of each question column contain the rating scores 1-7.

Many of the dimensions are different so it's gets complicated. For example, sales rep 1 has 2 groups (with varying number of users between groups1 and 2) and questions asked (for sales rep 1, group 1, there were 5 unique question IDs but varying number of users). I dropped two questions so the dimensions fit but ideally I'd like to run my CFA with them included.

Thank you anyone that has the willingness to attempt to help!

Comment: Aren't you basically already there? `df %>% select(repID, user, 'Customer question', Rating) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = 'Customer question', values_from = Rating)`? If not, can you clarify what's wrong with that solution?

Comment: Thanks for your code: when I tried your syntax the error is "error in select, unused arguments.... My problem was the package MASS masked the function select and I thought it was an error with my strategy! This helped VERY much and what I needed. Is there an easy loop to clean the dimensions by each sales rep to have the same format without individually checking each sales rep's questions by group?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I don't know what you mean by that last question. You might have to ask a new question for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Give these a examples a try, basically include whatever columns you want combined at the top in names_from = c(...) and leave out the column(s) you want to appear in the rows. In the third block below I left out repID so the row will be unique for each RepID + User combination across columns of questions.

```
df <- data.frame(repID=c("rep1", "rep2", "rep3", "rep4"),
             Ques=c("A1", "A1", "b2", "c1"),
             Rating=c(1,2,10, 6),
             User=c(92, 223, 22, 22))

widedf <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = c(repID, Ques), 
          values_from = Rating,
          names_sep = ".", values_fill=0) 

widedf2 <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Ques, 
          values_from = Rating,
          names_sep = ".", values_fill=0)
```

Comment: This creates NA's on the user row. For example, user 1 rates sales rep 1....row 1 = 5, NA, NA, NA, NA. row 2 for user 1 rating sales rep 1 = NA, 5, NA, NA,NA. If I could collapse the NA to take on the other responses it would work but not all users answer the same number of questions in order. This makes a loop challenging. Without a loop I'll have do this 200+ times since the dimensions aren't all the same.

Comment: You'll get NA because it is not possible to summarize items that don't exist. You can use the `values_fill=0` argument if you want them to be zero or some other default value.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was going down a dead end. That's good to know about the fill function. The issue was dplyr was being masked by MASS::select

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out. I've had that little conflict waste a good chunk of my time too!